# How to check the object is already restored from Glacier?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I'm working with Glacier objects in my node app. I want to know that a specific file is already restored from Glacier or It's currently being restored. I know "getObject"/"listObjectV2" methods can be used to identify the storage class of the file. But that's not my usecase. So i tried

```
export const restoreFromGlacier = async (params) => {
   await s3.restoreObject(params).promise();
};
```

it's throwing an error if the file is being restored. But when i run it again for an already restored object, it is restoring again. But i expected an error there.

Can anyone help me with this ?